# What are some NPAPI video plugin alternatives for Chrome?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, npapi, ppapi

Was: "**PPAPI (Pepper) video plugin -NaCl module failed - how to resolve?**"

Google's [Say Goodbye to Our Old Friend NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) blog post indicates that NPAPI plugin support will cease by the end of 2014 (in favor of PPAPI).

We have considered the option of using the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) libraries to create our own video plugin to simply decode RTSP encoded H.264 video streams on the client - important because we need as near real-time video display (avoiding transcoding latency).  Using the ffmpeg libraries, there is still a 3-5 second delay in decoding the stream, not as fast as running [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) with the `-benchmark` option.

In trying [Google's PNaCl recommendation](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1), we just got the LOADING status and the following error:

> NativeClient: NaCl module load failed: PnaclCoordinator: Compile
>   process could not be created: ServiceRuntime: failed to start

We don't need an encoder, simply decoding the incoming stream to images would be fine - or other suggestions?

What are some NPAPI alternatives to solve this problem?

Comment: This question is a little open-ended - you should ask about either a specific problem like your PNaCl issue or about NPAPI alternatives in general.

Comment: ffmpeg with the equivalent of fflags nobuffer may help.  What are you trying to accomplish here, a web player with low latency video plugin?

Comment: @rogerdpack - A web player with low latency video plugin without NPAPI.

Comment: I've heard of people using flash player and getting low latency before (in this particular case, ffmpeg -> wowza -> flash player) IIRC.  Or I suppose if you want the painful route you could write your own PPAPI or NPAPI plugin that wraps libav.  If you try ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -i <your input> -f sdl "sdl out" that should show you the latency ffmpeg/libav at minimum introduces.

Comment: Try this http://rtpstream.com/nacl_player_api/